# CPU is working, but not getting a signal on keyboard / monitor / mouse. No beeps / No POST

Tags: bios, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I have an ASUS H97M-E motherboard with UEFI BIOS. 
I changed the BIOS priority settings to boot first with network,
then DVD, and then HDD.

After that, when I restarted, it doesn't work.

- No beep; I can't even enter into BIOS setup.
- Blank screen on monitor / keyboard and mouse are not getting signals from CPU.
- POST process is not running.

Solutions I tried already:

- Removed RAM chip and fix it again
- Reset CMOS battery / jumpers settings for BIOS
- Checked by changing power supply
- Tested monitor
- Removed processor and inserted again
- Tested HDD / DVD by removing and reconnecting them.
- Video cable
- Cleaned the dust

What else can be a problem?

Comment: If you have restored the firmware settings to their default values and it still doesn't work then you have a hardware issue.

Comment: I reset with jumper and CMOS method but I still can't see BIOS. How I confirm that it restored the default firmware settings.

Comment: If you removed the CMOS battery then you restored the firmware settings.  If the machine does not even POST it means something is wrong with the motherboard and/or CPU.  How did you determine the CPU is "working" if the machine does not POST which is typically the built-in self test which normally indicates if something is working.

Comment: I determined CPU is working because fan is working, heat sink is running, motherboard LED light is ON. CPU is getting power and giving signal back by turning ON. what is not working is POST that is related to BIOS. and I don't know Can I install BIOS with USB if I can;t go into BIOS setup

Comment: Your heat sink fan turning on isn't good evidence your CPU is actually functional given your system isn't even attempting to POST.  It sounds like you bricked the motherboard when you made the modification.

Comment: so it means the last option is to change the motherboard, because I tried all the components of motherboard is not faulty. ? and I have spare one.

Comment: Conversely, how do you *know* that the POST process is not running?  If you’re not seeing anything on the display, that *might* be a monitor problem, right?

Comment: You say no beeps, but I assume you actually have the motherboard speaker plugged in? You wouldn't believe how many times people have told me no beeps, but didn't have the speaker plugged in.

Comment: @scott I have changed the monitor and even checked the monitor with another cpu.It is perfectly working fine.Its not just monitor even keyboard and mouse are not getting light or signal from cpu.

Comment: @Drzoo yeah I have plugged in speaker but no beeps from them.

Comment: Make sure no other USB devices and no drives are plugged in.  1 stick of memory, and CPU; it has to post (should beep)  Then add monitor (integrated graphics first) and keyboard (to motherboard USB not front panel) to try and gain some output and control; might try PS/2 instead of USB.  Swap in the other motherboard if you have really been that thorough.

Comment: Another CPU with same configuration, I changed boot settings and re-Image that PC successfully with network boot OS image, and after restart it has same problem. Help me , I can't changed motherboard of all computers when I do some boot priority change and they will end up  in this die state.

Comment: @Damon I heard a big sound of fan, heat sink and CPU turn on but no beeps, as well as when I connected the monitor, monitor lights turn to yellow and no signal received by CPU. I don't know what kind of problem all CPUs are suffering

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and thought the problem was the PSU; however I solved it by using different RAM slot instead as the PSU was fine.